# Canbus bit stuff Error

Tags: can

I was communicating two  stm32f4 discovery board and i wanted to create some failure scenario to take precautions. I shorted CANH & CANL and pulled VCC, GND respectively. But now my both of board cant communicate via CANbus. 
LOOPBACK mode works well. Communication starts.. (SLAK=0, INAK=0) but later, TEC= 0xF8 , error passive =1 warning=1 and busoff=1 and last error code is = bit dominant error. What will i do now ? My mcu's CAN peripherals are down ?? Please give me a solution.

Comment: `My mcu's CAN peripherals are down ??` ... are you asking if the peripherals are down? ... do you not know if they are down?

Comment: @jsotola i already removed. I don't know what is happening now. It is initiliazed well. But there is a problem while transmitting or receiving. I wonder that this problem based on internal HW problem or external HW problem and it can be fixed or not ?

Comment: shorting the signals may have overloaded something to the point of failure ... can you post a link to the schematic? ... include a description of which pins you shorted, and what size resistor you used to short them and what else was connected to those pins

Comment: @jsotola I was working well via Canbus till i tried to create shorting failures. I used so small pcb 2 SN65HVD251DR IC , 2x100nF to each VCC-GND, and 2x120 ohm for each CANH & CANL. Last thing i did  before this problem is shorting one of tranceiver IC's CANL to VDD and VSS directly.

Comment: check the inputs and outputs with an oscilloscope

Comment: @jsotola  is there any possibility of damaging CAN somehow, while even enters initiliazing and normal (listening can line)  mode ?

Comment: anything is possible ... you have to do basic trubleshooting .... otherwise, throw parts at the problem, which means replace the transceiver chips

Comment: @jsotola I will.

Comment: @jsotola UPS! my problem is ACK Error... I read wrong sorry.

Comment: What do you mean with "...and pulled VCC, GND respectively"? Did you remove the supply to the transceiver or what?

Comment: Regarding ACK error, do you have 2 functional nodes on the bus? Stuff error typically means that one line is shorted somehow (or far less likely, facing EMI) so that's a different kind of error entirely.

Comment: @Lundin  Last thing i did and most probably caused to failure is shorting one of Can Low shorted to VCC and GND respectively. After doing that, my mcu's last error code was bit dominant error and one time i saw ack error. Main problem seems as bit dominant error. Btw this is a good sign or not i dont know but LOOPBACK works well, both of mcu enters init and normal mod (listening) well. It might be an internal shorting or open circuit on mcu??

Comment: It is _very_ hard to kill CAN transceivers, I don't think I've ever managed and then I'm absolutely sure I've accidentally shorted the CAN signals to 24V or GND many times. It could theoretically be broken, but it is more likely that the problem is elsewhere. If in doubt, replace it.

Comment: @Lundin so weird.. I pulled Rs pin to ground and it worked. Huh i really got tired.

Comment: On this particular TI part, it should always be grounded unless you intend to fiddle around with slope control. If you leave it floating there's no telling what will happen.

Comment: @Lundin thanks a lot anyway. CAN is managing error management itself. If TEC or REC exceeds 255 , it resets peripheral by hardware or sw optionally. This is valid for all errors ? For example, when wrong data send, crc gonna be wrong and this problem gonna fall error state ?? Are the any solution except auto reset or retranmission of message ? I want to meet all failure scenario and handle can completely.